# Get JButton from another JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to get one jbutton when I click another jbutton.

[Here the link for sample code(Log in as jbutton,asdf as a password)](http://notepub.com/#note=558654)

```
//File Name= test1.java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test1 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test1();
    }

    public test1() {
        super("Using JButton");
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("First");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked first button");
            }
        });
        content.add(button);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Second");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked second button");
            }
        });
        content.add(button2);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If I click "First" button, I want to hide "second" button. My Expectation is like,"

```
button.setName("something");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      System.out.println("You clicked first button");
      btn2=getButtonByName("something");
      btn2.setVisible(!btn2.isVisible());
   }
});"
```

Comment: What does it mean '*get one button*'? It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please post your code along with a question. Preferably make it an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Max I have tried to post code,But I have got "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon." this error message. I do not know what to do.

Comment: yep, there is a `{}` button in the toolbar to format the code.

Comment: But it's tooltip said Use <pre> tag for coding. So I use <pre> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [setVisible(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) to change visibility, here is an example based on posted code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

    public test() {
        super("Using JButton");
        Container content = getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JButton button = new JButton("First");
        final JButton button2 = new JButton("Second");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked first button");
                button2.setVisible(!button2.isVisible());
            }
        });
        content.add(button);

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked second button");
                button.setVisible(!button.isVisible());
            }
        });
        content.add(button2);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: But my expectation,`button.setName("firefox");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You clicked first button");
    btn2=getButtonByName("firefox");
                btn2.setVisible(!btn.isVisible());
            }});`

Comment: @Firefox101 if the question is about `getButtonByName` - you can write lookup by name method using [getComponents()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29). See this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GetAllComponentsinacontainer.htm).